# NSFileSystemFreeSize returning inaccurate free disk space?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I'm trying to find the amount of free disk space on my iPhone and i've searched through several older post already. Most of these post utilizes NSFileManager to retrieve the NSFileSystemFreeSize value.

However, it seems like the number from NSFileSystemFreeSize is inaccurate when compared to the number I see from my phone's settings>general>about>available.

I get these following values:

- NSFileSystemFreeSize: 2287063040 (~2.28 GB)
- Phone's Available setting: 5.77 GB
- iTunes: 5.67 GB Free

Code I used:

```
+ (NSString*)getFreeDiskspace
{
NSDictionary *atDict = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/" error:NULL];
unsigned freeSpace = [[atDict objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] unsignedIntValue];

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", freeSpace];
}
```

Other information:

- Phone used: iPhone 7
- OS Version 11.2.1
- Phone is plugged into macbook so that I can built via xCode directly

Can anyone explain to me why NSFileSystemFreeSize doesnt match with the phone and iTunes? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There many way to get the free space

1、

```
NSString *tempDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary<NSFileAttributeKey, id> *att = [fileManager attributesOfFileSystemForPath:tempDir error:nil];
NSNumber *freeSize = att[NSFileSystemFreeSize];
const long long freeSpace = [freeSize longLongValue];
```

2、 only iOS 11 or later

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory()];
id AA = [url resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey] error:nil][NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey];
NSLog(@"\nURLVolumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage : -----------\n%@", AA);
```

3、f_bavail or f_bfree for use

```
- (const long long) diskSpace {
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
struct statfs tStats;
statfs([[paths lastObject] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &tStats);

// for total space
//    const long long total_space = (long long)(tStats.f_blocks * tStats.f_bsize);
//    return total_space;

// for freespace:
const long long free_space = (long long)(tStats. f_bavail * tStats.f_bsize);
return free_space;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try unsignedLongLongValue instead of unsignedIntValue?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS settings UI doesn't report the "real" free space available. Because everything that you store in `Library/Caches/` and `tmp/` can be requested by the OS, it's considered as free space. 
Also in the UI, sizes are displayed in base 10 and not base 2.